# Unrecognised field when insert in a ManyToMany relationship in symfony

Tags: symfony, many-to-many

I try to make a flush with a relationship manytomany, but I have an error that tells me "unrecognised field: insurance".

I would like to register one or two insurance (s) that the doctor has chosen, but I have errors during the flush with the relationship manytomany that there is between a doctor and an insurance

**Entity Medecin**

```
  /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, inversedBy="medecin")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
 */
private $assurance;

 /**
 * Add assurance
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance
 *
 * @return Medecin
 */
public function addAssurance(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance)
{

     $assurance->addMedecin($this);   
    $this->assurances[] = $assurance;


}

/**
 * Remove assurance
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance
 */
public function removeAssurance(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance)
{
    $this->assurance->removeElement($assurance);
}
```

**Entity Insurance**

```
  /**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin", mappedBy="assurance")
 */
private $medecin;

  /**
 * Add medecin
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin
 *
 * @return Assurance
 */
public function addMedecin(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin)
{

    $this->medecins[] = $medecin;
}

/**
 * Remove medecin
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin
 */
public function removeMedecin(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin)
{
    $this->medecin->removeElement($medecin);
}
```

**Twig**

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="assurance" class="form-control" placeholder="Assurance" name="assurance" multiple required>
                            <option value="">Assurance *</option>

                               {% for assur in assurances %}

                                <option value="{{ assur.nom }}" >{{ assur.nom|upper }}</option>


                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

**Controller** where i try to retrieve the select value

```
    public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if ($user === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Utilisateur Inexistant');
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $repo = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin');
    $specialiteRepo = $em->getRepository('DoctixAdminBundle:Specialite');

    $assuranceRepo = $em->getRepository('DoctixMedecinBundle:Assurance');

    $medecin = $repo->findOneBy(array(
        'user' => $user,
    ));

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {

        if ( ($pass = $request->get('pass')) != ''){
            $medecin->getUser()->setSalt('');
            $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
            $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($medecin->getUser());
            $password_encoder = $encoder->encodePassword($pass, $medecin->getUser()->getSalt());
            $medecin->getUser()->setPassword($password_encoder);
        }

        $medecin->setSpecialite($specialiteRepo->find($request->get('specialite')));
        $medecin->getUser()->setAdresse($request->get('adresse'));
        $medecin->getUser()->setNumTel($request->get('telephone'));
        $medecin->setQuartier($request->get('quartier'));
        $medecin->addAssurance($assuranceRepo->findOneBy(array(

            'assurance' => $request->get('assurance'))));

        // Save
        $em->flush();

        // redirection avec le status http 301 ::)))))
        $url = $this->generateUrl('medecin_parametre');
        return $this->redirect($url, 301);

    } else {
        return $this->render('DoctixMedecinBundle:Medecin:editProfile.html.twig', array(
            'medecin' => $medecin,
            'specialites' => $specialiteRepo->findAll(),
            'assurances' => $assuranceRepo->findAll()
        ));
    }
}
```

But i have the error "Unrecognised fiel: assurance" when i try to flush

[capture of my ormexception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMAG0.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I found a solution to my backup problem in my relationship ManyToMany, I made changes in my two entities, at the level of the collections of my entities.

**Entity Medecin**

```
   /**
 * Add assurance
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance
 *
 * @return Medecin
 */
public function addAssurance(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance)
{
             if (!$this->assurance->contains($assurance))
    {
        $this->assurance->add($assurance);
        $assurance->addMedecin($this);
    }
 }

  /**
 * Remove assurance
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance
 */
public function removeAssurance(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Assurance $assurance)
{
         if ($this->assurance->contains($assurance))
    {
        $this->assurance->removeElement($assurance);
        $assurance->removeMedecin($this);
    } 
 }
```

**Entity Assurance**

```
   /**
 * Add medecin
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin
 *
 * @return Assurance
 */
public function addMedecin(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin)
{
         if (!$this->medecin->contains($medecin))
    {
        $this->medecin->add($medecin);
        $medecin->addAssurance($this);
    }
  }

  /**
 * Remove medecin
 *
 * @param \Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin
 */
public function removeMedecin(\Doctix\MedecinBundle\Entity\Medecin $medecin)
{ 
        if ($this->medecin->contains($medecin))
    {
        $this->medecin->removeElement($medecin);
        $medecin->removeAssurance($this);
    }

 }
```

Thanks you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I see some things:

1 - When you use many-to-many you need to define a join-table between two entities. [many-to-many](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional).

2 - Your collections fields are assurances and medecins (with 's' at last).

$this->assurance**s**->removeElement($assurance);

$this->medecin**s**->removeElement($medecin);

3- Your error is because you search(findOneBy) on assuranceRepo an Assurance Entity and this entity doesn't have assurance field. Medecine has assurance field.

```
$medecin->addAssurance(
          $assuranceRepo->findOneBy(array(
            'assurance' => $request->get('assurance'))));
```

to

```
$medecin->addAssurance(
              $assuranceRepo->findOneBy(array(
                'name' => $request->get('assurance'))));
```

Comment: I applied your remark 2. 
I understood your remark 3, but how to have the value of the select I chose. because I get the value with the request-> get ('insurance')

Comment: $request->query->get('id'); or $request->request->get('category', 'default category'); https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/introduction/http_fundamentals.html

Comment: But I see again your code and I have some observations. When you need to search something, the best option is ID to search, but in twig you set name as the value to select, there you need use ID and in the controller, you use findOneById with selected value.

Comment: In Assurance entity, Does It have assurance field?

Comment: in assurance entitty it haven't assurance field, only id, name and logo as property

Comment: Hi @MohamedSacko, ok. You search $assuranceRepo (Assurance Entity) is wrong because Assurance entity doesn't have assurance field.

Comment: i've add a capture of my log of my ormexception. it shows well that my insurance recover well the value of the insurance that I chose which is stane, but why it does not register

Comment: $object = $assuranceRepo->findOneBy(array(
            'assurance' => $request->get('assurance'))));

if($object)  $medecin->addAssurance($object);

Comment: Other observation, in assurance select, it accepts multiple options, so in the controller, you can have multiples values.

Comment: yes it's exact, it accepts multiple options.
I followed your recommendation, and it's show me the same error : "unrecognised field: assurance "

Comment: OK, the error is because Assurance doesn't have that field, remember you search an Assurance entity, not Insurance. So in search use findOneByName($request->get('assurance'))

Comment: But I think that the best search mode is ID and you can edit twig value="{{ assur.getId }}" or assur.id and use findOneById() or findOneBy(array('id'=>$id))

Comment: ok i doing your recommendation, and i have no error but registration does not take place in the database

Comment: I don't know what other errors exist because I don't know your complete entities and database. Remember you need a join table when you use many-to-many.

Comment: Another recommendation, check if($object) $medecin->addAssurance($object); it is really executed, add else option and print_r("no entity found");die;

Comment: $em->persist($medecin); $em->flush();   :p

Comment: i have doing the check with that: ** if ($object) {
                $medecin->addAssurance($object);
            } else{
                print_r("pas d'objet trouvé");
                die();
            } **. And i do the persist but the recording isn't work.

Comment: I don't know ¿really any data change on db? Other good practice is separate objects, eg: $user = $medecin->getUser(); .. $user->set.. and $em->persist($user). I have worked with Symfony from 6 years and really work fine. When I do simple forms I use SonataAdminBundle.

Comment: any data change on db. I use the simple html form.Maybe i have the problem with the owning and inverse side ? @cuchu

Comment: Do you add join table between entities many to many? Maybe you need to read the documentation and try with simples tests.

Comment: my problem is resolved, i have updated my post in adding the answer.I made changes in my two entities in level of addAssurance and AddMedecin and it's resolved my problem. You can see it. Thanks again for your help during all the day.Thanks

Comment: Good for you! please mark this question as resolved ;)